# How to pass pass/reference a dictionary in a request

Tags: python, django, request

I have made an API call with the function below that I am testing on Postman. It takes in an id(dictionary) and deletes the doctor with that id. So the solution works as it is.Problem is , the id is hard coded - id = {"id": 11} .How do I reference it so that I can feed it in postman instead of hard coding?
I have tried using  `id = request.GET.get("id")` and adding it as a parameter but it didn't work for me.Any assistance will be highly appreciated

Views.py

```
class DoctorBillingPayments(GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    @classmethod
    @encryption_check
        def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            id = {"id": 11}
            try:
                result = {}
                auth = cc_authenticate()
                res = deleteDoctor(auth["key"],id)
                result = res
                return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except Exception as e:
                error = getattr(e, "message", repr(e))
                result["errors"] = error
                result["status"] = "error"

            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

api_service.py

```
def deleteDoctor(auth, data):
try:
    
    headers = {
                "Authorization": f'Token {auth}'
    }
    url = f'{CC_URL}/doctors/'
    print(url)
    res = requests.delete(url, json=data, headers=headers)

    return res.json()

except ConnectionError as err:
    print("connection exception occurred")
    print(err)

    return err
```

Comment: add parameters to your GET request, key as  'id'   and value as 11

Comment: check it, https://toolsqa.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/nggallery/postman/Param_Automatic.png

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a REST style here and passing the id through to the view using a path argument, like so:

- `DELETE /doctor/{id}`

To do so, you'd define the parameter inside your `urls`:

```
url(r'^doctor/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', DoctorBillingPayments.as_view(), name="doctors")
```

then you can access it from `kwargs` for an example request like `DELETE /doctor/123`

```py
class DoctorBillingPayments(GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @classmethod
    @encryption_check
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = int(kwargs['id'])
        try:
            result = {}
            auth = cc_authenticate()
            res = deleteDoctor(auth["key"],id)
            result = res
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            error = getattr(e, "message", repr(e))
            result["errors"] = error
            result["status"] = "error"

        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```